# Mercurial qfold ALL patches?

Tags: mercurial

Turns out there is no `hg qfold -a`.

I tried `hg qfold $(hg qunapp)` and `hg qunapp | xargs hg qfold` but couldn't get it to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

With your xargs approach, did you remember that qfold only folds *unapplied* patches into an *applied* patch?  This worked for me (Windows) to fold all patches into the first patch:

```
hg qpop -a    # remove all patches
hg qpush      # apply first one
for /f %i in ('hg qunapplied') do hg qfold %i  # fold remaining patches
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... we could add a `-a` flag... But until we do, I would use the [histedit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) or [collapse](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CollapseExtension) extensions or maybe just do it myself:

```
$ hg update qparent
$ hg revert --all --rev qtip
$ hg commit -m 'Everything in one commit'
$ hg qpop -a
```

You then need to remove the patches -- perhaps you can just remove `.hg/patches` entirely, or you can delete some of them and edit `.hg/patches/series` to match.

Comment: shambulator: I did not suggest `hg qdelete` since it also lacks a `-a` flag.

Comment: So maybe we need to add two `-a` flags :)

Answer (score 0):

```
hg qunapp | xargs -I'{}' hg qfold '{}'
```