# Mercurial patch queue collapse

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I am using the patch queue to achieve something like what this person asked here:

[Why can't I rebase on to an ancestor of source changesets if on a different branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145755/why-cant-i-rebase-on-to-an-ancestor-of-source-changesets-if-on-a-different-branc)

However, what I would like to do, is that when I have all the patches in the queue, rather than apply them one by one, I would like to collapse them into one changeset. Is this possible, by either a switch I didn't find, or by when pushing the patch from the queue, not committing, just having a local change.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to try `hg qfold <PATCH>...`.  See the [EditingHistory](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EditingHistory#Editing_recent_history_with_MQ) wiki or `hg help qfold` for further info.

There is no `--all` option for the `qfold` command, so you must specify each patch file manually or write a script / one-liner if you want to make this a batch process.  See this related SO question:

[Mercurial qfold ALL patches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715016/mercurial-qfold-all-patches)